# how can calculate the cost for running up to 500 working threads

Tags: java

I implemented a system to handle 500 socket connections using Java, each connection in its own thread.
So when all connection are alive, I have 500 Threads running.

Will a server Intel® Xeon® Processor E5620 with 8 GB of RAM be enough to handle all these threads?

Whether the answer is yes or no, how can I calculate the cost?

sample code:

```
    Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(500);
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket socket;


    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (true) {
        try {

            if (serverSocket != null) {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
            } else {
                continue;
            }

            SocketClient client = new SocketClient(socket);//socket client is responsible for handling string values that will be read from socket, and insert values to the DB

            executor.execute(client);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            connectedDevices.remove("Unknown" + i);
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Um, it depends on what the threads are doing. Loading small files? Or running chemical simulations?

Comment: The threads are dealing with Strings, splitting received values and insert them to DB

Comment: @kdureidy That gives us no idea how much work has to be done. How many values do you expect the server to receive in the average second? What do you need to store in memory?

Comment: each connection will send String like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9:33:33:1,1,0
and I split this String, and store it to the DB

Comment: I receive new String from each connection every 5 seconds

Comment: So you're look at, say, 100 database operations per second. The choice of database will have more effect on performance than almost anything else.

Comment: at worst case yes, it is 100 operations, but I save based on some values in the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any more-or-less modern computer will handle 500 threads, it is not a problem (I suppose you do not allocate GBs of memory in each of them)

problem - **how long it will take for each thread to finish** it's execution when all 500 are run simultaneously

for example if each thread do not block others via shared resources (like db), and takes 1 second from start to finish, and we have 8 thread cpu - this will mean that only 8 thread will run really simultaneously, so each second only 8 threads will finish, other will wait to start, so last thread will finish approximately in 63 seconds, common timeout is about 30-60 seconds, this will mean that results of last thread will not reach the client

so, to do approximate understanding you can calculate execution time of one thread (T seconds or miliseconds), and then you will find how many **requests per second** your server will be able to handle

of course it will be very aproximate value, as context switching between threads also takes time

Comment: Threads will be running indefinitely, i am sure it will not consume more than 2 GB of memory, but what about the CPU, I dont want the CPU usage to reach 100%. do you think it's possible to run all these threads simultaneously?

Comment: @kdureidy what is the sense in infinity running threads? this will mean that only first 500 clients will be handled, if even 1 thread will run indefinitely - it will consume 100/8 of processor time

Comment: indefinitely not infinity. each thread will expect a message to arrive every 5 seconds

Comment: @kdureidy what is the condition for thread to stop and start handling new client?

Comment: in ideal case, it should never stop, and the only reason to stop, is losing socket connection

Comment: @kdureidy ok, should never stop = infinity, and we return to my question - why do you need it, maybe its enough to have 1 thread, which will read data from all opensockets and process data as soon as it come?

Comment: well, I need each connection to be on it's own thread, because it's not just for reading data through that socket, it's also giving the ability to send and manage data through that socket.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39099/discussion-between-kdureidy-and-ilya-bursov)

Comment: This is flat wrong. There is no guarantee that a thread is woken up ever again if there is other work to do. On a 1-core machine with 2 threads, it is by definition that thread 2 will get its share. On an 8 core machine with 500 threads, the next thread will be chosen more or less by random. It can (and does) happen, that one of these 500 threads will never wake up before the client runs into timeout. The correct answer is therefore: you cannot calculate how long a thread takes to finish, only make a good guess under certain assumptions.

Comment: @TwoThe you haven't read question/answer and didn't understand example

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to exactly measure the cost of another Thread, it depends on way too many factors.

However for your special case Java offers the NIO concept, using [Selectors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) to enable a few threads to process all incoming requests by knowing which connection actually needs processing. Unless you are a Java Guru (or for some other reason need to write this yourself) I strongly recommend to use existing libraries, as there are way too many pitfalls to reason the reinvention of the wheel once again.

You will always have the peak performance if you have 1 Thread per core, if you can make sure that it will never block/sleep. And Selectors + non-blocking IO will make sure of that.